VS Code/Chrome Debugger Causes Breakpoint in Angular Application Generated Webpack File
I have an angular application that I work with using VS Code and Chrome running with the debugger port set to 9222. However, the debugger likes to throw its own breakpoints into the webpack-generated files, usually main.js.
I've tried to adjust my launch.json, but the problem hasn't gone away.
Here's the relevant launch.json snipped:
      "name": "Chrome (Debug 4200)",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9222,
      "urlFilter": "http://localhost:4200/*",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**",
        "${workspaceFolder}/**/main.js"
      ]

Can anyone tell me what I can do to main it stop inserting its own breakpoints?
